# How to set the DataTextField property?

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-3.5

In .Net 3.5 and VB.NET VS2008
How to set the DataTextField property in this link:

http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/ASP/Simple_Databinding.html

It says:

> Now update the page to build a list of TechnologyDescriptors  and to attach the collection of TechnologyDescriptors for each control. For each control, set the DataTextField property to "TechnologyName" (to map it to the TechnologyDescriptor's  TechnologyName property). This will ensure that the technology name will appear in the control. Then set the DataValueField  for each control to "Description" to map the Description property to be the associated value.

How to do this ?

Comment: There would probably be a property called DataTextField. You'll have to assign it as instructed. `control.DataTextField = "TechName";`

Comment: I added like this but not working (im using VB.NET):
  
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
            <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="Description">TechnologyName</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:ListBox>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

Comment: Are you actually data binding here, or just creating a static list?  If you are databinding, what's your data source?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're data binding to a [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4d7ktzs(VS.71).aspx), you can set the value of DataTextField in either the asp code:

```
<asp:ListBox id="Listbox1" 
     DataSource="<% databindingexpression %>"
     DataTextField="DataSourceField"
     DataValueField="DataSourceField"
     AutoPostBack="True|False"
     Rows="rowcount"
     SelectionMode="Single|Multiple"
     OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnSelectedIndexChangedMethod"
     runat="server">

   <asp:ListItem value="value" selected="True|False">
      Text
   </asp:ListItem>

</asp:ListBox>
```

or using code behind:

```
ListBox1.DataTextField = "DataSourceField";
```